# Represetation of a smooth function in the neighborhood of its zero-set

Tags: real-analysis, functions, smooth-manifolds

Consider $k$ smooth functions $g_i(x)$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $k<n$. The set $G$ is defined as $G=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n|g_i(x)=0, i=1,...,k\}$. We also assume that the Jacobi matrix $\frac{Dg}{Dx}$ is full-rank on $G$.

Let $F(x)$ be a smooth function s.t. $F(x)=0$ for any $x\in G$.

I wonder if is it true that in the neighborhood of $G$, $F(x)$ can be represented as $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(x)g_i(x)$, where $f_i(x)$ are some smooth (at least on the neighborhood of $G$) functions and $g_i(x)$ are as defined above? If it is not true, can one impose some additional constraints on $g_i(x)$ or $F(x)$ to make it true?

One obvious problem occurs if $g(x)$ has zero of higher order on $G$. Consider, e.g., $\mathbb{R}^2$, $g(x)=(x-y)^3$, $G=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x=y\}$ and $F(x)=x-y$. In this case, function $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}$ is singular on $G$. It seems that the full-rank condition imposed on the Jacobian matrix obviates this problem